# Error while importing csv file to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, csv-import

I have installed Cassandra-2.2.7 and it's working fine. I have created a table with schema
 `create table student(name text,id int primary key,age int,branch text);` with id being primary key. I have a CSV file with the headers (name,id,age,branch) which I want to import into this table. The CSV file contains some 3000 rows. Now when I try the import command,

```
copy students from 'students.csv' with HEADER=TRUE;
```

It shows error, `invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

When I did `select * from student;` command, the schema is as follows,

```
id,age,branch,name
```

The table columns have somehow changed to alphabetic wise. As `id` is the primary key, it remained as first column. How can I import the data to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the order of the columns in the CSV file when running the copy command:

```
copy students (name, id, age, branch) from 'students.csv' with HEADER=TRUE;
```